# If I log into with VPN to a remote server can they see my files?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

When I log in to a VPN via my Windows 7 system. I can then access the files on that remote server. However, can others also access the files in my computer while I am logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, whoever set up the vpn can set up things like that. Is it a possibility, yes. Is it 100% for sure, no.

Comment: how do I figure out if that is indeed the case? is there a way to find out from my side?

Comment: Ask someone on the network you are connecting to to try and access your share.

Comment: If you are using windows 7 you can set the VPN as a "Public" connection that will have stricter firewall rules and you can have the Public profile block incoming windows share requests. (it is likely off by default anyway)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is **yes**. VPN is a network. When you connect to a VPN, it's as if you were physically connected to the network. Like the network your computer is connected to at work, admins or users with the *correct privilege* can remote into systems or view files on systems on the network.